# Is there a convenient way to turn XML into a suds.sax.element.Element instance?

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am using [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) to make some RPC calls that require arguments like

```
suds.sax.element.Element('html').append(Element('body'))
```

This is cumbersome especially if the needed XML is constant. Is there a convenient way to just get the Element by parsing text, for example

```
fromstring('<html><body></body></html>')
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO.
There's no other simpler way to deal with the XML creation with SAX.
I believe that's because the nature of SAX in creating XML (read [this](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/03/12/py-xml.html)).

Why was choosen SAX and not a DOM API ?

> The suds.sax module was written
>   because elementtree and other python
>   XML packages either have a DOM API
>   which is very unfriendly or (in the
>   case of elementtree) do not deal with
>   namespaces and especially prefixes
>   sufficiently.

Comment: It was really easy to write a little SAX parser to create Element() from a string, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is YES.
You can use [suds.sax.parser.Parser](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.sax.parser.Parser-class.html)

(btw, why is this not on the SUDS docs  directly??)